# $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)") exact match of this in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i tried with

```
var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox].checked');
```

its working and i need unchecked checkbox values also

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")
```

like this i need in javascript please help me

Comment: Please speak in coherent sentences.

Comment: i think this question already asked ..

Comment: if($('input[type=checkbox]').checked) {
         console.log('checked');
    } else {
         console.log('Not checked');
    }

Comment: var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'); is the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) method along with [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) selector

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)')
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').value)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Also, note you are using [Class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) when prefixing `.`

Comment: Thanks @satpal its working perfectly